# Regex error inside class-eval block

Tags: ruby, regex, class-eval

I've got some code to add methods to a module from simple definitions for talking to remote resources via a wrapper class around a REST client.

```
def service_function(function_name, method, uri, parameters)
  class_eval <<-RUBY
    def #{function_name}(params)
      if !(#{function_name}_required_params - params.keys).empty? || \
           !(params.keys - #{function_name}_params).empty?
        raise Errors::InvalidParameters.new(service_name, __method__,
                                            params.keys, #{function_name}_params)
      end
      WebServices::ServiceRequest.perform(self.domain, #{uri}, #{method}, params)
    end

    def #{function_name}_params
      #{function_name}_required_params + #{function_name}_optional_params
    end

    def #{function_name}_required_params
      #{parameters}.select { |param,req| req }.keys
    end

    def #{function_name}_optional_params
      #{parameters}.select { |param,req| !req }.keys
    end
  RUBY
end
```

Before I can even run the code, just requiring the gem I'm building into IRB spits out this error:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'web-services'
SyntaxError: (eval):7: unknown regexp options - rt
```

The offending line is:

```
WebServices::ServiceRequest.perform(self.domain, #{uri}, #{method}, params)
```

Removing the "#{uri}" argument fixes it, even leaving in the "#{method}" argument. Does anyone out there have a clue as to why this might be? I'm about at my wit's end.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `url` that looks something like `/something/rt` and that will look like a regex literal in here:

```
WebServices::ServiceRequest.perform(self.domain, #{uri}, #{method}, params)
```

You need to escape and quote `#{uri}` so that it looks like a string inside the heredoc, that way `class_eval` will see `perform(..., '/something/rt', ...)` and be happy. You might have similar issues with `#{method}`.

Comment: The thing is I'm not passing anything in yet, this in just on require. When I remove #{uri} it works perfectly.

*EDIT* Nevermind, I found a stray line of code from earlier testing on it that was being executed during the require step. I feel a bit silly now. Thanks for the reply. =)

Comment: For posterity's and google's sake, the solution was to replace #{uri} with "#{uri}".

Comment: @user1034016: That should be safe but the truly paranoid would want to make sure that `uri` didn't have any double quotes or do something like `"#{uri.inspect}"` to get them escaped.